# phpMyAdmin Block Access to Single Database

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

I want to restrict access to a single database in phpMyAdmin. Is this possible? 
I am making a application that will be installed on client PC and will work in local server. I want to restrict others viewing the database and tables.

Or is it possible someway through `.htaccess` as database name is passed onto URL -

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/#PMAURL-4:index.php?db=dbname&table=&server=1&target=&token=457a0c4ec42cbe72f72786efa1aaf530
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block it by putting this rule on top of `phpmyadmin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)db=dbname(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

But there might be other ways of blocking access to this DB by changing user permissions directly in MySQL database also.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There are 2 ways to access db. First through phpmyadmin and second directly through mysql cmd line. Your answer will block the phpmyadmin route but still mysql is open.

Comment: But you started your question as `I want to restrict access to a single database in phpmyadmin. Is this possible?` which is giving impression that you're probably trying to block the DB access from phpmyadmin only.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an incomplete answer because it doesn't fully restrict access. I can still manipulate that database from the SQL tab. You're right that it helps keep people from getting in by directly clicking a link, but it's not a great solution from a security (or user-friendly) standpoint.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch: As commented above this is solution for what OP wrote: `I want to restrict access to a single database in phpMyAdmin. Is this possible?`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest use MySQL permissions to restrict the user from seeing the other databases. When you create the user for your application, don't select any global privileges (on the first screen when creating/editing a user). If you're creating the user, you'll be taken back to the Users screen where you should click Edit Privileges (if you're editing an existing user, just scroll down a bit). Halfway down the Edit Privileges page for your user, you'll see "Database-specific privileges". Select your database from the dropdown and then edit their privileges on the resulting page.

This way, you'll use the MySQL privilege system to restrict the users to only accessing the database you want them to use. Restrictions based on blocking the phpMyAdmin URL are incomplete and give a false sense of security (because SQL queries can still access the other databases, the other databases are shown, and even some phpMyAdmin options will allow the user to interact with those databases), not to mention the extreme user un-friendliness that happens when you block their attempted action without explaining why (as would happen if you rewrote or redirected based on the URL).

Comment: but thats available on web database. I want to do in local server.

Comment: Sorry, but what are you talking about? I don't really understand that statement. You said "I want to restrict others viewing the database and tables." This is the proper way to do that (regardless of whether you mean when users access it from phpMyAdmin or your application). There's no difference to your database whether you're accessing it over the web, through a local application, or any other means; that's sort of the point of the database. Client programs (phpMyadmin or your custom application) all use the same permissions and data storage means. Can you further clarify what you mean?

Comment: ok now i understand it. Earlier i din't get u. We can set privileges with grant. I haven't tested it but if it works it will be the best solution.